# ArangoDB work was stopped

Tags: arangodb

Here is

> The description for Event ID 256 from source ArangoDB cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Service "/_admin/aardvark" encountered error 400 while handling GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/graph/Notes?nodeLabelByCollection=false&nodeColorByCollection=false&nodeSizeByEdges=false&edgeLabelByCollection=false&edgeColorByCollection=false&nodeStart=comp%2F3357363&depth=0&limit=1&nodeLabel=name&nodeColor=%232ecc71&nodeColorAttribute=w&nodeSize=power&edgeLabel=&edgeColor=%23cccccc&edgeColorAttribute=
>   via ArangoError: AQL: invalid traversal depth (while instantiating
>   plan) C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at Route._handler (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\apps\system_admin\aardvark\APP\aardvark.js:536:18)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at next (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\foxx\router\tree.js:412:15)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\node\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:10029:25 C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at Middleware.authRouter.use (C:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\apps\system_admin\aardvark\APP\aardvark.js:106:3)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at next (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\foxx\router\tree.js:410:7)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at next (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\foxx\router\tree.js:410:7)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at dispatch (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\foxx\router\tree.js:426:3)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp
>       at Tree.dispatch (c:\Program Files\ArangoDB3 3.3.7\usr\share\arangodb3\js\server\modules\@arangodb\foxx\router\tree.js:135:7)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\V8\v8-utils.cpp out of
>   memory in V8 (Committing semi space failed.)
>   C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\ApplicationFeatures\V8PlatformFeature.cpp
>   `anonymous-namespace'::oomCallback 103

Comment: Please report errors on GitHub: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new Make sure to include the minimum required information such as operating system, ArangoDB version and steps to reproduce or at least a description of actions that led to the error.